# How to store and display an SQL result where the columns do not match any of my entities

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am writing a spring boot application to perform certain jobs on a MySQL database. One of the things I am having trouble with is getting the average temperature per day from the database.

My @entity looks as follows:

```java
@Entity
public class SensorData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long sensorDataId;

    @Column(
            name = "timestamp"
    )
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;

    @Column(
            name = "temperature"
    )
    private Float temperature;

    @Column(
            name = "humidity"
    )
    private Float humidity;

    @ManyToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            optional = false,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "department_id",
            nullable = false
    )
    private Department department;
}
```

And department entity as follows. I am working with department (1)"A", (2)"B" and (3)"C".

```java
@Entity
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long departmentId;
    @Column(
            name = "department",
            unique = true
    )
    private String department;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "department",
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private List<SensorData> sensorData;

}
```

The problem I am facing is that I need to make a query that returns average temperature per day per department. In my attempts to do this I have written the following JpaRepository function:

```java
@Query(value = "select round((dc.temperature),3) as temperature 
     ,dc.department_id,dc.timestamp from db_uppg.sensor_data dc group by department_id,dc.timestamp",nativeQuery = true)
    List<?> findTemperature();
```

And a controller function that returns a thymeleaf template averageTemperature.html:

```java
@Controller
public class IndexController {

@Autowired
    private SensorDataRepository sensorDataRepository;
  @GetMapping("/averageHumidity")
  public String avgHumidity(Model model) {

    List<?> list = sensorDataRepository.findHumidity();
    model.addAttribute("allHumidity", list);
    return "averageHumidity";
  }
}
```

And finally my thymeleaf template:

```html
<table class="table table-dark table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Average Temperature</th>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="humidityList : ${allHumidity}">
        <th scope="row">-</th>
        <td th:text="${humidityList.humidity}"></td>
        <td th:text="${humidityList.datetime}"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My IDE warns me that it cannot resolve humidity and datetime in my thymeleaf template. I assume it's because I am using `List<?>`, and Java cannot understand the data this list contains?

I am not sure what other ways I can achieve displaying a result where the columns requested do not match any of my original entities.

Answer (score 0):

That query returns `List<Object[]>` as the actual type, so use that instead of `?`. Then in your service layer (or the controller if you don't have a service layer), convert the rows to suitable DTOs with those fields (`humidity` and `datetime`).

The resulting code could look something like

```
List<HumidityDTO> list = sensorDataRepository.findHumidity().stream()
                                   .map(h -> new (HumidityDTO(h)))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If `HumidityDTO` has a constructor taking an `Object[]` parameter.